Determine all possible values ​of the sum $S=a+b+c+d$
The problem
Let $a$ and $b$ be two integers for which the interval $(a,b]$ contains 20 integers and let $c,d$ be two natural numbers for which the interval $(c,d)$ contains 24 natural numbers. Determine all possible values ​​of the sum $S=a+b+c+d$ for which the function $f:\mathbb{R} \ \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=cx+d$ satisfies the condition $f(f(a))- f(b)=2022$
my idea
For the interval $(a,b]$ to contain 20 integers it means that $b-a=20$ and for the interval $(c,d)$
to contain 24 natural numbers $d-c=25$ which also means that $c+b=a+d+5$
Also $f(f(a))- f(b)=2022= c^2a-cb+cd$
I thought of saying that $(b-a)(d-c)= bd-bc-ad+ac=500$
I don't know if all of this is going to help, but I think it is relevant. Thanks!

Your expression for $f(f(a))-f(b)$ is not correct.  Please check it and if you cannot find the error show your derivation.  Note that $c$ must divide $2022$

@RossMillikan Sorry for the misspelling I edited it.

Now you can eliminate $d$ in favor of $c$.  Note $2022$ has eight factors and $c$ has to be one of them.

@RossMillikan But how is this going to help? All I got to is that $2022=c(ca-b+c-25)$ Should I also eliminate b in favor of a?

Yes.  That gives an equation you can solve for $a$ once you plug in each value of $c$

$(c,d)$ (open interval) contains $24$ natural numbers but not $c$ or $c$ which themselves are natural numbers?  Why obfuscate?  Why not just say $d = c+25$

$b = a + 20$ and $d=c + 25$ so $a+b+c+d= 2(a+c) + 45$.  $f(x) = c(x+1)+25$ and so ... just do it.  You'll have a quadratic in terms of $c$ and $a$ with $a,c$ integers and $c$ positive.

Did I make a arithmetic error?  I get that $f(x) = c(x+1)+25$ and $b=a+20$ so $f(a) - f(b) = c(a+1)+25 - c(a+21)-25=-20c$ and so $f(f(a)-f(b))=c(-20c + 1)+25=2025\implies 20c^2-c + 1997=0$ and so $c = \frac {1\pm \sqrt{1 -4\cdot 20\cdot 1997}}{40}$ which is not a real number.  Did I err?

@fleablood I still dont understand why you calculate f(20c)?

.... because $f(a)-f(b) = -20c$ by my calculations.  So $f(f(a)-f(b))$ would have to be $f(-20c)$ wouldn't it.  Obviously I'm making an are somewhere as I get nonsense.  But seriously.  If $f(x) =cx + d$ then $f(a)-f(b) = (ca+d)-(cb+d)= c(a-b) = -20c$ doesn't it?

Wait..... is $f(x) = cx + d$ or is $f(x) = c(x+d)$.  Those are ENTIRELY different statements.

@fleablood I'm repeating myself...Why did you calculated f(f(b)−f(a))
and equaled it to 2022...shouldnt it be f(f(a))−f(b)=2022. Look better at the parentheses...

@fleablood Did you understand? Correct me if I'm wrong.

You are not repeating yourself as the first time you asked me why I calculated "$f(f(b) - f(a))$ instead of $f(f(a) -f(b))$" which 1) was not what I had calculated and 2) you made the same error with the parenthesis as I did.  ... Okay.  $f((fa)) = c(f(a) + 1) +25= c(c(a+1)+25)+25= c^2a + c^2 + 25c + 25$ and $f(b)=c(b+1)+25=c(a+21)+25=ca+21c+25$ and $f(f(a))-f(b)=c^2(a+1)+4c=2202$

@fleablood Sorry for my misspelling ,then. Did you got the same results as me in final?

Continuing on your answer. Since, $f(f(a)) - f(b) = 2022 = c^2a - cb + cd$
$b-a=20$
$d-c=25$ (mistake in your answer)
Expanding this equation further gives us:
$c(ca-b+d) = 2022$ and on using the range equations, we get:
$c(ca+c-a+5) = 2022$
Assuming, $(ca+c-a+5) = \lambda$
Therefore, $c\lambda = 2022$
Now, factorizing $2022$, we get 6 pairs of $\lambda$ and c,
$(c, \lambda) = (1, 2022), (2022, 1), (2, 1011), (1011, 2), (337, 6), (6, 337), (3, 674), (674, 3)$.
Using these pairs we arrive at 3 values of $(a,b,c,d)$, other pairs do not satisfy the initial conditions like $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and so on:
$(a,b,c,d) = (1004, 1024, 2, 27), (334, 354, 3, 28), (-1, 19, 337, 362)$
Hence, $S = a+b+c+d$ can have 3 values i.e., $S \in \{2057, 719, 717\}$
Let me know if I made a mistake somewhere.
Thanks.

Thank you so much for your answer! But I think the pairs for c and $\gamma$ you put arent correct shouldn't them be :(1,2022), (2022,1), (2,1011), (1011,2),(3,674), (674,3), (337,6), (6,337)?

Correct me if i'm wrong

I got as a result $(a,b,c,d)=(1004,1024,2,27),(334,354,3,28),(-1,19,337,362)$

@IONELABUCIU Yeah, you're correct. My bad. I was in a hurry.

No problem. Thanks for your help !
